# Значение из HtmlHelper

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

На форме cshtml расположен html heplper, который генерирует следующую разметку

```
<input id="ref.addr" name="ref.addr" class="k-textbox k-state-disabled" data-role="fiasInput" readonly="" style="width: 65%; opacity: 1;" value="" title="40000000 Область Город">
```

Мне необходим атрибут title, пробовал различными способами результата нет.

```
var addr = "";
addr = $("#ref.addr").val();

addr = $("#ref.addr").attr("title");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот так сработает (инпут получаем по значению атрибута `name`):

```js
var addr = $("[name='ref.addr']").attr("title");
console.log(addr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="ref" name="ref.addr" class="k-textbox k-state-disabled" data-role="fiasInput" readonly="" style="width: 65%; opacity: 1;" value="" title="40000000 Область Город">
```

Ваш вариант не работал, потому, что `"#ref.addr"` воспринимается как :

достать элемент с `id=ref` И с классом `addr`

Так как такого элемента предположительно нету, ничего небыло найдено и достать атрибут не получалось